# How common is addressing someone by their mother's name in Islamo-arabic culture?

Tags: prophet-isa, names, maryam

In most ancient Semitic languages and times, it seems that a person was usually known by their name followed by "son of [their father's name]."

Is there a reason, **besides the virgin birth,** that Isa ibn Maryam is identified as the son of **Mary** in the Qur'an (i.e. a woman, the mother; e.g. such as the high devotion Christians had at the beginnings of Islam for Mary the mother of Jesus), rather than, say, David, as Jesus is in the New Testament (it being, as far as I know, almost unheard of that a man is identified as the son of his mother specifically unless the context makes it relevant)?